# List.extend() is not working as expected in Python

Tags: python

I have a list `queue`and an iterator object `neighbors` whose elements I want to append to the list.

```
queue = [1]
neighbor = T.neighbors(1) #neighbor is a <dict_keyiterator at 0x16843d03368>
print(list(neighbor)) #Output: [2, 3]
queue.extend([n for n in neighbor])
print(queue)
```

Output:

```
[1]
```

Expected Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: try: `queue.extend(list(neighbor))
`

Comment: That doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already exhaust the iterator `neighbor` when you use it in the `list` constructor for printing, so it becomes empty in the list comprehension in the next line.

Store the converted list in a variable so you can both print it and use it in the list comprehension:

```
queue = [1]
neighbor = T.neighbors(1) #neighbor is a <dict_keyiterator at 0x16843d03368>
neighbors = list(neighbor)
print(neighbors) #Output: [2, 3]
queue.extend([n for n in neighbors])
print(queue)
```

Comment: Or just `queue.extend(neighbors)` will be fine

Comment: Amazing! Such a minute mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You consumed the iterator already:

```
print(list(neighbor))
```

Take that line out.